# how to export data from aspxgridview into MS Excel 2007

Tags: asp.net

I am using the devexpress grid view in my project and also the exporter tool of devexpress, but that doesnot support exporting file to MS Excel 2007 format.

Can anybody know any other method through with data can be exported to MS Excel 2007 format.
This is must as there are over a lac record in the grid and only MS Excel 2007 can be used.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guide works quite well:
http://rongchaua.net/blog/c-create-excel-file-from-datatable-without-using-excel-object/